# Background image not working in Chrome mobile, works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a webpage and I am down to just a few things left, and this one for the life of me I cannot figure out.  I am using Angular to build the page along with HTML and CSS.  My issue is that when I view the page in a mobile browser  using Chrome, the background is not correct.  However I can view the same page in Firefox and it will work fine.  I believe that I have everything set correctly.  I'll paste some screenshots and some code below of what I'm talking about.

[What it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Vl8.png)

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrq7Z.jpg)

It looks like the background is wanting to zoom in on that first page.  The thing is, ALL the other pages are fine.  Background works no problem. Here's the relevant code:

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    background: none no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-top: 70px;
    transition: background ease-in-out 0.8s;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Angular:

```
myWebsite.controller('NavController', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    });

    $scope.home = function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/hsds/img/hsvwall.jpg)';        
    };
    $scope.events = function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/hsds/img/theavenue.jpg)';
    };
    $scope.dances = function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/hsds/img/theavenue.jpg)';
    };
    $scope.madjam = function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/hsds/img/theavenue.jpg)';
    };
    $scope.about = function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/hsds/img/theavenue.jpg)';
    };
    $scope.connect = function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/hsds/img/theavenue.jpg)';
    };
    $scope.learn = function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/hsds/img/theavenue.jpg)';
    };

});
```

Navbar HTML: 
Here I have it so that when a user clicks on the link, it does a fade to the background in question.

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse" ng-class="isCollapsed ? 'collapse' : 'in'">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-click="home()"><a href="#/home">HOME</a></li>
            <li ng-click="events()"><a href="#/events">EVENTS</a></li>
            <li ng-click="dances()"><a href="#/dances">MONTHLY DANCE</a></li>
            <li ng-click="madjam()"><a href="#/madjam">MADjam</a></li>
            <li ng-click="learn()"><a href="#/learn">LEARN</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                <li ng-click="about()"><a href="#/about">ABOUT HSDS</a></li>
                <li ng-click="about()"><a href="#/board">HSDS BOARD</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
            <li ng-click="connect()"><a href="#/connect">CONNECT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Please help, I have no idea why this isn't working on Chrome mobile when it works fine on everything else.

Tim

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]. Use a jsFiddle/codepen or the provided snippet tool on SO. We need the output of your code, not the input in order to help you. That way we could inspect and tell you what CSS property of what element needs to be adjusted in order to fix your issue.

Comment: My apologies, site can actually be accessed at www.timmcintire.org/hsds

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. What device are you using? And what version of Chrome? There are Chrome Windows, Chrome Mac, Chrome Android Tablet, Chrome Android Mobile, Chrome iPhone & Chrome iPad. Anyway, the correct order of background properties in shorthand is: `color|image|repeat|attachment|position`. So it should be `black no-repeat fixed center center`. However, it doesn't seem to change the way the background is rendered. I assume you know you're loading different bgs for different devices, right?

Comment: You might want to add `body{height: 100vh; overflow-y:auto;}` to your CSS. This might fix it. You've set the `background-size` to cover and when your have a small amount of content the image in only drawn under the content. So you need to draw it over all screen.

Comment: I might try that, I fixed it for the time being by removing all but the one "background-size: cover" and keeping it as a fixed background.  Which is why you probably can't reproduce it now.  I also created a mobile image instead.  I'm interested to see if the 100vh works.  Thanks guys